# VS 2008 can't open projects in Windows 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, windows-7

I've installed VS 2008 and SP1. I've tried to load a solution that has a WCF project and it complains that "This project type is not supported by this installation".

I've tried the devenv.exe /setup but that didn't help.

If it matters, this is all on Windows 7. On a Windows Vista installation I have no problems with the same solution (also VS2008 w/sp1).

Comment: I'd suggest developing on a supported operating system. Windows 7 is beta for a good reason.

Comment: I am surprised no one has pointed out the obvious - this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turned out I had made a pretty bone-head maneuver during the install and didn't install the Web Developer portion, only the C# portion. Once I installed that, all was well.

Answer (score 4):

You're best off using VS2008 on a supported operating system. Windows 7 is in beta and you're more likely to run into problems....just like this one...

unless your goal is to test VS2008 on Windows 7 in which case what you want to do is contact Microsoft in order to give them feedback.

Comment: I started to report a bug to MS about this but found that other users had no problems at all. Unfortunately it was my own stupidity when installing VS and I just missed it. Please see my own answer below for more. Surprisingly, the error told me exactly the problem and I just assumed it was a bug.;)

Answer (score 0):

Please report this problem at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/. I'm sure they *really* want to hear about Win7 problems.

Answer (score 0):

I develop in VS2008 daily on Windows 7 and I haven't run into this issue. 
However, I installed it on Vista then did the upgrade option so maybe that's part of the reason.